# How many reports on Facebook comments are needed to get an offending comment deleted from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, comments

Is there a number of reports needed to get a comment deleted? Or is it not automatic?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it's not automatic and that there are a group of employees who moderate these.

Comment: Employees that check every reported comments on many different languages??? Seems difficult but not impossible

Comment: That's a big assumption on my part. There's nothing to say that they do anything like that, or even anything at all. Or that they get through even a quarter of the reports.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the [Statement of Rights and Responsibilities](http://www.facebook.com/terms.php) and see if the comment actually needs to be reported.

I believe it increases in moderation down the list.

*Spam or scam*
A lot of users spam other walls with their Facebook pages or groups.

*Contains hate speech or attacks an individual*
This could just be a heated argument between two users with nothing better to do than argue over Facebook.

*Violence, crime, or self-harm*
Here it becomes near a legal issue so I would believe the moderation is very tight here.

*Nudity, pornography, or sexually explicit content*
Same as above. Without even the need for report. I have some friends who were models that placed up their semi-nude shots only to be removed immediately after.

There must be some sort of issue-handling service that rates the reports. Because there were many times that I have reported comments only to realize the page admin could have just removed the comment.